# What is the radio models distance limit?

Tags: radio, modeling

From how far could be a flying machine operated from a static station?

What is the physical limit? 1km ? 5km? or 10km?

Is the only problem of creating "drones" operated from your appartment the components in the emitter / receiver instruments? Or is there something more?

I mean, radio signal is basically going at the speed of light, a little slower in our atmosphere, because it is not a vacuum, but still I don't see a real time problem for 5 km at all.

Could somebody explain that to me?

Which physical problem is the issue in constructing flying "drones" operated from your appartment with a camera attached to it?

Comment: Unmanned space probes can be controlled over a distance of many millions of miles by radio from earth

Comment: Use a cell phone, light weight, built in camara, GPS, good fidelity, out of sight range, lower development cost, rechargeable, little interference. Just an idea.

Comment: I don't understand. Cell phone?

Comment: Well, typical drones communicate with the hive mind via the central plexus which uses a sub-space transceiver. Sub-space communication is many times faster than the speed of light with potentially millions of light-year range, although then latency is a problem. But 5km should not be an issue. I don't think another camera is needed as the standard issue laser eyepeice provides a good enough image for most drones. Of course if subspace is damaged (omega particle perhaps) then normal radio waves may be used, but their intensity diminishes with distance according to the inverse square law.

Comment: @geometrical What are you talking about? What do you mean by sub-space. We have problems to detect bosons and need 126 GeV to do it and even then we cannot detect them (they exist very short time) and only by reconstruction of the path of other particles we can claculate where they were and how long. Are you serious? If you were joking I would suggest to remove your comment or go to science fiction and fantasy room. Thank you and I am waiting for other explanations from others.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an **unanswerable** question about the **usage or end-user capabilities** of **unidentified** equipment.

Answer (score 2):

Radio signals lose power as they travel over distance. This wikipedia article explains this nicely: [Path loss](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_loss).

You can now calculate the maximum possible distance with your senders signal strength and your receivers sensitivity limit.

In reality the maximum working distance can be much shorter, as the received singal must be above noise level.

Answer (score 1):

There is no physical limit.  However, the received strength of a radio signal decreases with the square of the distance from the transmitter.  Eventually you have to transmit so much power for the signal to be correctly received that it is either impractical or illegal.

NASA can control space probes at great distances because they use very high gain antennas, and there is little ambient noise in space at the frequencies they use.  Actually "gain" of a antenna is a bit misleading.  You never get more power out of a antenna than you put in.  What "gain" really means is that the power is concentrated in a narrow beam.  That means in the direction of the beam, the antenna appears to have provided gain relative to a more uniform emitter.  You may put 1 W into a antenna that concentrates the 1 W in such a narrow beam such that along the beam you see the same power as ordinary antenna would deliver with 100 W in.  The difference is that you get very little off-axis of the beam.

The military controls drones remotely by using satellites to relay signals to the drone.  The bad guys aren't usually willing to put up antennas for you where you want to fly the drones.  With enough satellites, there is always some antenna available above wherever you are.

Answer (score 1):

In practice, loss of a line of sight (to obstructions and/or horizon), and man-made interference sources play as much or more a role in limitation as the inverse square law.